# generating the combinations which are fixed under symmetry operation

Tags: combinatorics, polya-counting-theory

I have the following problem:
If I have a system with a certain symmetry, for example, a square or a 2x2 grid and each grid point can have 2 states, for example, occupied or not occupied, or colored and not colored, how can I generate the set of all possible combinations which are invariant under symmetry operation.
I know how to get the reduced number of combination using the orbit-stabilizer theorem, but I could not figure out how to actually get all the combinations of coloring.
Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Use Burnside's lemma for these kinds of problems.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel: He wants to generate them, not count them.

Comment: @darijgrinberg But in the process of counting them, you generate them!

Comment: Not with Burnside's lemma, at least.